# 5 days from a variable date

Tags: php, date

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$date = '06-17-2013';

if (strtotime("now") > strtotime("+5 days", strtotime($date))) {
   echo '5 days have gone by';
} else {
   echo 'not yet';
}
```

This function always returns '5 days have gone by' . I could never get it to return 'not yet'
Why?

Comment: Maybe because Londoners don't use MM-DD-YYYY format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use is `$date = '17-06-2013';`  (DD-MM-YYYY)

or `$date = '2013-06-17';` (YYYY-MM-DD)

and not

<strike>`$date = '06-17-2013';`</strike>

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying your date by `YYYY-MM-DD`. `strtotime` doesn't seem to support the `MM-DD-YYYY` notation.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the SPL DateTime object.

Try this:

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-06-17');
$date->add(new DateInterval("P5D");
$now = new DateTime();
if($now > $date) {
    echo "5 Days have passed";
}
else{
    echo "not yet";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change `'06-17-2013'` to this `'06/17/2013'` it will work as expected

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$date = '06/17/2013';

if (strtotime("now") > strtotime("+5 days", strtotime($date))) {
   echo '5 days have gone by';
} else {
   echo 'not yet';
}
?>
```

There is a difference between using forward slash / and hyphen - in the strtotime function.

```
Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator   
between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American 
m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the 
European d-m-y format is assumed.
```